# How to save multiple images to a resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and creating a real estate application that store information about apartments.

I have an Apartment model, views and a controller that work so I can CRUD apartments.

Now, I'd like to add the ability to add multiple images to an apartment.

I've installed the gem carrierwave, mini_magick and fog gems.

I created an Image model with that has a picture(string) column and and apartment_id(integer) column. Then I created a belongs_to/has_many relationship between Image and Apartment.

My question is: How can I create an instance of the Image model in the Create Apartment view?

I'd assume I'd do something like this in the apartment controller, but I'm not sure:

```
  def new
    @apartment = Apartment.new
  end

  def create
    @apartment = current_user.apartments.new(apartment_params)
    **@image = @apartment.images.new(?)**

    if @apartment.save **&& @image.save**
       flash[:notice] = "Congratulations! Your apartment has been added."
       redirect_to apartments_path
    else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your listing. Please try again."
       render :new
    end
  end

private

def apartment_params
  params.require(:apartment).permit(:street, :from_date, :to_date, :to_date_open, :flex_dates, :price, :price_neg, :agent_fee, :furnished, :package, :flights, :beds, :baths, :description)
end
```

Also, I'm not sure how to change the code in the view:

```
<%= form_for(@apartment) do |f| %>
  <% if @apartment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>
      <% @apartment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :street %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :street %>
  </div>

  **<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>
    <%#= f.hidden_field :picture_cache %>
  </div>**
```

Any guidance on how to add images while creating a new apartment would be great.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

How I have approached this problem in the past is two have two other models. I would create one model that is a gallery and one that is a photo.

The Photo can have more information on it you care about name or description. The photo links to the gallery so it knows which gallery it belongs to.

The Gallery then has just a name and links to an apartment. I like separating it out a it in case you want to do anything special like pick which photo is first in a gallery or something.

If you don't care then you could easily just do another crud model with photos and give it the apartment_id.

I would handle photo uploads later and not at the start of listing the apartment, it will help get people more invested when the barrier to listing an apartment is lower.

So the commands I would run if you are doing the it with a gallery are

`rails g scaffold gallery name:string apartment:belongs_to`

`rails g scaffold photo name:string information:text photo_url:string gallery:belongs_to`

or with no gallery

`rails g scaffold photo name:string information:text photo_url:string apartment:belongs_to`

You will have to update the photos model and controller to work with carrierwave after this though.

Comment: Thanks @salinn!! The way you described the relationships is helpful. Would you be able to give me guidance on how to update the apartment controller to implement crud for photos and galleries?

Comment: @NechamaGoldman so the way I described you wouldn't have to update anything with the apartment controller. What you would do is go through your normal steps then on the show page for the controller you would add a photo section and put the form for photos. I don't think you need a gallery here personally. Does that make sense?